# Fastest way to load numpy array that has one column of strings and the rest floats

Tags: python, numpy, load

I am using the following code to load numpy arrays in a loop. It is by far the slowest line of my loop.

```
data = cp.load('/content/drive/My Drive/Share/Daily Data/Chunks/dataArray.npy',allow_pickle=True)
```

The file is around 1GB, or about 200,000 rows with 400 columns. The first column is strings, and the rest are floats. Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

It must be reloaded in each iteration of the loop, there is no way around this.

Sometimes when I run my code, interrupt it, then start again, this line goes from 15 seconds to under 1 second, and I have no idea why or how to reproduce it consistently...

Comment: What's `cp.load`?

Comment: cupy version of np.load

Comment: What's the array's `dtype` and `shape`.

Comment: 200,000 x 3,000, dtype = float64